# Problema al ejecutar sentencia SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo un problema al ejecutar una sentencia en SQL Server

```
CREATE TABLE venta (
    idVenta INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
    Fecha DATE NOT NULL, 
    Cliente_Cedula INTEGER NOT NULL,
    producto_idProducto INTEGER NOT NULL,
    empleado_Cedula INTEGER NOT NULL,
    cantidad INTEGER NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY ('Cliente_Cedula')
    REFERENCES cliente ('Cedula')
    FOREIGN KEY ('empleado_Cedula')
    REFERENCES empleado ('Cedula')
    FOREIGN KEY ('producto_idProducto')
    REFERENCES producto ('idProducto')
    );
```

Error:

Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de 'Cliente_Cedula'

Answer (score 0):

después de constraint tienes que poner el nombre de la constraint, antes de decirle de que tipo es. Para el índice más de lo mismo. Corregido quedaría así:

```
CREATE TABLE venta (
idVenta INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
Fecha DATE NOT NULL, 
Cliente_Cedula INTEGER NOT NULL,
producto_idProducto INTEGER NOT NULL,
empleado_Cedula INTEGER NOT NULL,
cantidad INTEGER NOT NULL,
INDEX fk_venta_cliente NONCLUSTERED (Cliente_cedula),
constraint fk_venta_empleado FOREIGN KEY  (empleado_Cedula) REFERENCES empleado (Cedula),
constraint fk_venta_producto FOREIGN KEY  (producto_idProducto) REFERENCES producto (idProducto)
);
```

Comment: Edite la pregunta

Comment: Qué versión de Sql Server es? si no simplemente quitala del create table y ejecutala a parte con:   create index fk_venta_cliente on venta (Cliente_cedula);

Comment: SQL Server 10.0